# What happens to skill levels gained via training if I use a Fateweaver?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

If I go and buy some training for my skills (say I used 2 mercantile trainers and an alchemy trainer) and then use a fateweaver to reset everything, what would happen? Would I lose all the training, or would it stay after my reset?

Equally, if I use a higher level trainer (say a 4-6 one) and reset, does that change what happens?

Answer (score 10):

Trainer and race points will remain, you reassign all skills you've earned. This works especially well to maximize your skills points when you reset.

[Here](http://www.ign.com/wikis/kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning/Trainers) is a list of trainers for your benefit.

Also, to answer your second question (I think). You can reset your skills with the fateweaver in order to make your skills meet the particular trainers requirements. For example if you're at a stealth trainer and your stealth skill is to high you can reset so you can utilize him then in the future if you reset again that skill will remain in your skill set.

Comment: Book points will remain, too. [This answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/50003/how-can-i-maximize-my-skill-points-gained-in-kingdoms-of-amalur/50113#50113) has a lot of related info about skills in KOA.