# Do skill points from trainers disappear in Kingdom of amalur with a respec?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happens to skill levels gained via training if I use a Fateweaver?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/51090/what-happens-to-skill-levels-gained-via-training-if-i-use-a-fateweaver)

If, for example, I spend 100-150k gold on training lockpicking/merc/stealth skills, then I change my fate: do they disappear? or are they permanently unlocked in skills? (i.e They don't disappear from my skills and are now the default levels of them.)

Comment: You may be interested in this other, quite similar question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/50003/how-can-i-maximize-my-skill-points-gained-in-kingdoms-of-amalur

Answer (score 4):

Nope. Once you've trained with a trainer (or read a skill book), you get to keep that skill point for the rest of the game.

This means its possible to get a fateweaver to unbind your fate, level your skills to the appropriate range, and receive training from any trainer you missed out because your skill was too high the first time.