# Where can I find skill books?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I have found a couple of skill books that when read, leveled up my skill, one in sagecrafting and the other one in stealth.

Are the locations of skill books random? If it isn't random, where can I find all the skill books?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This information can be found [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/991142-kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning/61906765/690365087)

---

> **Alchemy:** Plains of Erathell, behind secret door near Urul Tusk
>
> **Blacksmith:** Warsworn Questline, Hall of Firstsworn Forge Room
>
> **Detect Hidden:** Traveler's Questline (Going Rogue, or later.)
>
> **Dispelling:** House of Ballads Questline, Ballads Library
>
> **Lockpicking:** Orieator's Tomb in Northern Forsaken Plain
>
> **Mercantile:** Motus Mining Outpost Questlines, Located in the fully upgraded house that is given as a reward.
>
> **Persuasion:** Reward for Paper Trail quest in Adessa
>
> **Sagecraft:** In the well at St. Hadwyn's Mission (House of Ballads questline)
>
> **Stealth:** Traveler's Questline (Going Rogue, or later.)

---

**To answer your question, the location of the books is very much static.**

Comment: During my playthrough, I found two different Detect Hidden books. The 2nd one I got was from the Traveler's quest and when I tried to read it, it wouldn't let me because it said I'd already read that book. It leads me to believe this is either an incomplete static list, or that in addition to the static locations, you can find the books randomly. I updated my answer to a related question [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/50003/3062) as well.

Comment: Very interesting, I'll have to look into it. But for the time being most of the internet can agree that the books indeed DO exsist in these static locations, and potentially more!

Comment: The Sagecraft book is at S. Hadwyn's Mission, but you don't go there during the House of Ballads quest line. It's in northwestern Glendara. Detect Hidden level 2 is required in order to loot the items in the well.