# Can you utilize both basic trainers?

Tags: pc, kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

Everywhere I look, there are *two* basic trainers for each skill. Can one use both of these trainers if they spaced their points properly and were ellidgible by level?

Example Coming from [IGN](http://www.ign.com/wikis/kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning/Trainers):

(0 to 3) Lyceum Grove in City of Ysa

(0 to 3) Molly Janick in Blue Bear Tavern in Emaire (western Forsaken Plain)

**Could I use both of these trainers?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use both trainers.  If your skill level is already too high by the time you meet them, you can reset your points at a fateweaver and get training from them before reapplying your points to that skill.

The only caveat is that it's possible (via a combination of racial bonuses and skill books) to make it so that you can't use both of the "lowest level" trainers because you're already past the maximum skill level to use them.  (Thanks to Sterno for pointing this out)

This question/answer goes into a bit more detail about how to maximize your skill points:

[How can I maximize my skill points gained in Kingdoms of Amalur?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/50003/how-can-i-maximize-my-skill-points-gained-in-kingdoms-of-amalur)

Comment: So essentially, I can get +4 points to each skill through trainers?

Comment: @Emerica. - yes, if you don't mind a bit of mucking about and the large amount of gold it would cost you.  Some of the skills might not be worth the effort, though.  (Lockpicking comes to mind)

Comment: Well I have been setting myself up to hit all the trainers on my first playthough. I find this game to a bit to easy when you do the research and watch where you put your points.

Comment: I respecced like mad and hit all the trainers and still ended with 2 million gold. Gold isn't an issue.

Comment: @agent86 You could theoretically miss out on a basic trainer if your race gives you +2 to a skill and you read a book for that skill before hitting both basic trainers for it..

Comment: @Sterno, edited, thanks for the note on that corner case.

Comment: I would also like to add through playing the game if you betray the Warsworn you can no longer utilize their trainers because they become hostile. However, I was able to sneak up on Ney Csalan in Mel Senshir and force her into dialog before she went hostile and I got the training. She tried to kill me instantly as soon as the screen faded back in. She must have been raging.