# Why can't I train anymore?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I trained up my detection skill to level one, I'm now trying to train it up again both from the same guy but for some reason he won't let me train anymore. It says that its for levels 0-3 and my skill is only level 1. How can I fix this so I can train again?

Answer (score 4):

You can only use each trainer once, refer to [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/50003/how-can-i-maximize-my-skill-points-gained-in-kingdoms-of-amalur) question for all of your skill related needs.